# Translating weather forecast terms into Russian

Tags: терминология

We are developing app that uses weather data from http://wunderground.com/ website

And, I'm a little bit confused with translating of these terms:

- **Mostly Sunny**
- **Partly Cloudy**
- **Partly Sunny**
- **Mostly Cloudy**

Now, with the help of [weather.gov](http://forecast.weather.gov/glossary.php) glossary service I found these descriptions of corresponding weather states:

**Mostly Sunny**
When the 1/8th to 2/8ths of the sky is covered by with opaque (not transparent) clouds Same as Mostly Clear, except only applicable during daylight hours.

**Partly Cloudy** Between 3/8 and 5/8 of the sky is covered by clouds.

**Partly Sunny** Between 3/8 and 5/8 of the sky is covered by clouds. The term "Partly Sunny" is used only during daylight hours.

**Mostly Cloudy** When the 6/8th to 7/8ths of the sky is covered by with opaque (not transparent) clouds. Same as Considerable Cloudiness.

Could you please help to translate these terms into Russian, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Russian Гидрометцентр has its own set of terms. Here is the authoritative link - http://meteoinfo.ru/forecasts/forcterminology

The approximate correspondence is:

Mostly Clear (Sunny) - Малооблачно; Небольшая облачность

Partly Cloudy (Sunny) - Переменная облачность; Облачно с прояснениями

Mostly Cloudy (Considerable cloudiness) - Облачно; Пасмурно; Значительная облачность

Answer (score 2):

- Mostly Sunny - малооблачно
- Partly Cloudly - переменная облачность, облачно с прояснениями
- Mostly Cloudly - пасмурно

Answer (score 1):

> Mostly Sunny / *Преимущественно солнечно* (daylight) or *преимущественно ясно* (any time)
>
> Partly cloudy (sunny) / *Переменная облачность* or *облачно с прояснениями*
>
> Mostly cloudy / *Пасмурно*

There is no phrase (used in weather forecasts) which would apply "partly cloudy" to daylight only, so just assign any of them for daylight and another one for the night time.